# command ordering in $.blockUI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use blockUI ([www.malsup.com/jquery/block/](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)). There is a little js.code:

```
function blockSite() {
    var loadImSize = 100;
    $.blockUI({
        message: '<img src="preloader_transparent.gif" width="' +
                loadImSize + 'px" height="' + loadImSize + 'px">',
    css: {
        top: ($(window).height() - loadImSize) / 2 + 'px',
        left: ($(window).width() - loadImSize) / 2 + 'px',
        width: loadImSize + 'px',
            height: loadImSize + 'px'
        }
    });
}
function unblockSite() {$.unblockUI();}
blockSite();
alert(3);
unblockSite();
```

How to use that the block-image appears before alert and the image disappears after alert closing? I need for a certainty the the usage

```
blockSite();
alert(3);
unblockSite();
```

instead of a

> $.blockUI{... ,onBlock: function() {...}, ...}

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable it's animation:

```
$.blockUI({..., fadeIn: 0});
```

Edit: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahmoodvcs/p5LHq/)